# How to select only x rows from a csv file for a pie chart

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, pie-chart

I have a *CSV file* containing a hundreds of lines here's a sample :

### **city.csv**:

```
City,JanTemp,Lat,Long
Indianapolis  IN,21,39.8,86.9
Des_Moines  IA,11,41.8,93.6
Wichita  KS,22,38.1,97.6
Louisville  KY,27,39,86.5
New_Orleans LA,45,30.8,90.2
Portland  ME,12,44.2,70.5
Baltimore  MD,25,39.7,77.3
Boston  MA,23,42.7,71.4
Detroit  MI,21,43.1,83.9
Minneapolis  MN,2,45.9,93.9
St_Louis  MO,24,39.3,90.5
Helena  MT,8,47.1,112.4
Omaha  NE,13,41.9,96.1
Concord  NH,11,43.5,71.9
Atlantic_City  NJ,27,39.8,75.3
Albuquerque  NM,24,35.1,106.7
Albany  NY,14,42.6,73.7
New_York  NY,27,40.8,74.6
```

What I want to do is create a pie chart representing `JanTemp` for every 10 rows.

Here's my initial code to create a pie chart for all the rows :

### script:

```
<script>



        var width = 500;
        var height = 500;
        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
        var donutWidth = 120;
        var legendRectSize = 18;
        var legendSpacing = 4;

        var color = d3.scale.category20();

        var svg = d3.select('#chart')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height)
          .append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + 
            ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
          .outerRadius(radius);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
          .value(function(d) { return d.JanTemp; })
          .sort(null);

        d3.csv('city.csv', function(error, dataset) {           
          dataset.forEach(function(d) {                             
            d.JanTemp = +d.JanTemp;                                     
          });                                                       

          var path = svg.selectAll('path')
            .data(pie(dataset))
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
              return color(d.data.City);
            });

          var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
            .data(color.domain())
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'legend')
            .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
              var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
              var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
              var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
              var vert = i * height - offset;
              return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
            });

          legend.append('rect')
            .attr('width', legendRectSize)
            .attr('height', legendRectSize)
            .style('fill', color)
            .style('stroke', color);

          legend.append('text')
            .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
            .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
            .text(function(d) { return d; });                       

        });                                                         


    </script>
```

The code is working yet the visualization is bad.

---

**The question is :** How can I create a pie chart for every 10 rows in the csv file ? (Where also, can I add the property to only get rows by 10 ?) Is it even possible ?

Comment: Side note: your CSV is malformed. The lat/lon values are denoted using a decimal comma whereas it should be a decimal point. This way the number of *comma-separated* data columns does not correspond to the number of columns defined by the header. According to [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) the *"header will contain names corresponding to the fields in the file and should contain the **same number** of fields as the records in the rest of the file"* (emphasize mine). It should be `Indianapolis  IN,21,39.8,86.9`.

Comment: ops! i haven't noticed that, i'll update it! thanks for the note!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to do this, the first is to simply repeat what you have already and create several SVGs, one for each piechart.

The second is a bit more elegant, and involves a single SVG controlled by D3.
You'll first need to reorder your data into chunks of 10:

```
function( alldata ) {
    var dataDivide = [], i, chunk = 10; 
    for (i=0; i<alldata.length; i+=chunk)          
    {
         dataDivide.push(alldata.slice(i, i+chunk));
    }
}
```

You can now use D3 to divide up your SVG and then set the chunks to be your data for each piechart:

```
    var svg.selectAll("g")
        .data( dataDivide )
        .enter()
        .append("g")
            // position the g, etc.
        .selectAll('path') 
        .data( function(d) {
            return pie(d); // d is a chunk
        }) 
        .enter() 
        .append('path')
            // etc.
```

Comment: Have I miss understood something?

Comment: What i wanted is : each 10 elements -> in 1 pie chat.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! it was great ! "return" was missing in your code i added it.